# how to register manytomanyfield in admin in django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-models

My model looks like this:

```
class Search(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region)

class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100")
```

In my `admin` when I register `Search model` and `Region model`,
I want to see the `User data` in the `Search model` and `search and user data` in `Region model`.
both in the `list_display` and `inlines` of the admin.  Since one is a `ForeignKey` and one is `ManytoManyField`, I am not clear how to get this working.
some help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this behavior isn't supported out of the box by django. I dont believe, but I may be wrong. I tried accomplishing the same then when I first started, and havent noticed any updates in the release notes.  But I'll dig around though and see if I can figure out a hack for you.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to get the User data visible on the inline on the Region admin screen easily. Below is a decent starting spot.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Search, Region

class UserInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = User

class SearchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UserInline,
    ]

class SearchInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Search

class SearchRegionsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Search.regions.through

class RegionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SearchRegionsInline,
        SearchInline,
    ]
```

If you're set on editing the user information from the Region admin screen, then you will want to create a custom form for the `SearchInline` so it has the fields from the `User` model and then populate the values in the `__init__` if an instance is passed in.